# Unexplained gap appearing between two divs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an unexplained gap appearing between two `div`s.

Here is an image of the situation:

[image]

It is the gap just above the red `div` that I want gone.

I want the red `div` to be `red` all the way to where the image is. How can I do that?

**Code:**

```
<script type="text/html" id="product-template">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-2 clickable" style="margin-top:20px; padding: 25px;">
        <div style="border-radius: 10px; border: 1px solid white;height: 270px;overflow: hidden;">
            <div style= "height: 200px; border: 1px solid white; 
                        border-top-left-radius: 10px; 
                        border-top-right-radius: 10px;
                        color: white; 
                        background: center no-repeat;
                        background-image: url(../../the_vegan_repository/product_images/alpro_custard.jpg);
                        background-size:cover;">
            </div>
            <div style="height: 70px; background: red;">
                <h6 data-bind="text: product.name" style="color: white"></h6>
                <h6 data-bind="text: shop.name" style="color: white"></h6>
                <h6 data-bind="text: shop.suburb" style="color: white"></h6>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle ? It would be easier to help you.

Comment: I declare sorcery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a `h6` has child of your bottom `div` and in bootstrap the headings from `h1` to `h6` have `margin-top:10px` and `margin-bottom:10px` "by default" so you need to reset that `margin` in `h6`.

Something like:

```css
h6 {
  margin-top:0
}
```